# using pandas.to_sql command without using sql alchemy - invalid identifier

Tags: python, database, pandas

I am trying to connect to a local mariadb database and insert some data into a table.

The table definition has already been created with:

```
CREATE TABLE asx_companies (stock_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, company_name TEXT,symbol CHAR(3),industry TEXT,yahoo_code CHAR(6));
```

My code to insert the dataframe into the database is:

```
from db import DB
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb as mariadb
HOST = 'localhost'
USER = 'josh'
PASSWD = 'josh'
DATABASE = 'stock_db'
db_connection = mariadb.connect(host=HOST,user=USER,passwd=PASSWD,db=DATABASE)
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('use stock_db')
cursor.execute('show tables')
prettyPrint(cursor.fetchall())
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Joshua/Documents/asx_data/asx_companies2.csv")
data.to_sql(con=db_connection, name='asx_companies', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

The error I am getting is when inserting the following from the dataframe:

> 1-PAGE LIMITED,1PG,Software & Services,1PG.AX
>
> ValueError: Invalid MySQL identifier '1-PAGE LIMITED'

Comment: Do you have proper column names in your data frame? Did your CSV have a header row?

Comment: hi andrew, no there are no column names in the dataframe because the tables structure is already defined via an SQL create table command. Does a dataframe need to have a header row to use the to_sql command? All column names in the sql table are defined with all lowercase and underscores.

Comment: Note this usage of `to_sql` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. You better just install `sqlalchemy` and use a sqlalchemy engine (but still combined with the ``MySQLdb`` driver) and see if that works.

Comment: Further to answer your question in the comments: yes, a dataframe should have matching column names to the table structure in sql.

Comment: thanks @joris I will look into sql alchemy. my sql table definition has a stock_id which is auto incrementing. How do I tell pandas python to insert into every other field in the table except that one (because I want it to auto increment?

Comment: You can just have a dataframe without this stock_id columns (but with all others) and append this. In such a case, the sql table will autoincrement the stock_id column itself